# CFFI UserWarning: 'point_conversion_form_t' has no values explicitly defined;

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm getting the following warning when running a scrapy crawler:

`C:\Users\dan\Anaconda2\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\cffi\model.py:526: UserWarning: 'point_conversion_form_t' has no values explicitly defined; next version will refuse to guess which integer type it is meant to be (unsigned/signed, int/long)
  % self._get_c_name())`

I hadn't been getting this in my previous Anaconda Python install on my Windows 10. I had to reset my environment and now I am.

It's not preventing the crawler from running, but it's kind of annoying. Can anyone tell me what might be causing this?

Comment: I just created an Anaconda virtualenv on an Ubuntu VirtualBox vm and am getting the warning there as well.

Comment: I found out that this is related to [OpenSSL](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/392) but still have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Actually, I got rid of the error by downgrading to cffi 1.2.1. Cffi seems to be the culprit to me.

Comment: @DanRoss thanks for the solution. I'm also getting the same userwarning message. I'm on windows 7 environment using Anaconda and Pycharm IDE. Can you tell how can i downgrade cffi.

Comment: @Ashish I used pip install cffi==1.2.1 from the command line. In PyCharm you have to go into the project settings and specify the version of cffi you'd like to use.

Comment: @DanRoss thanks for the answer.

Comment: Dan, would you consider providing your solution (the downgrade) as a response? It will be more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to cffi==1.2.1 ended up being the solution for me.